# Apache Camel + Amazon Kinesis

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, amazon-kinesis

I'm trying to create a route to consume streams from Kinesis and I couldn't find where to set the application name.

Is it possible?

If not, how can I consume only once the same Stream if I have multiple instances listening the same Kinesis "topic"?

I'm using the last version of camel boot and camel-aws.

What I did already:

1. set the `camel.springboot.name` and `spring.application.name` property
2. set the `userAgentPreffix` in the ClientConfiguration

Thanks.

Comment: I have the exact same question here :) - did you find any answers?